# inverse characters from a string using 'for i in string'

Tags: python

In python is there a way to inverse a string using a 'for i in string' but starting from the last char rather than the first? I would like to avoid using a counte rand I do not want to use INVERSE.
Thanks for the feedback!

```
string = 'caramelosticosis'
new_string = ''
cont = 0
for i in string:
    cont+=1
    new_string += string[-cont]



print(new_string)
```

Comment: You mean "reverse"?  Try reverse(string) or string[::-1] in your loop.

Comment: May I ask _why_ you are subject to these constraints? The best way to do it would just be `new_string = string[::-1]`.

Comment: well, they are not necesarily constraints, Just wanted to know if there is an alternate for i in 'string', but kind of inverse. but the answer provided by you and dmcc are super!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to just use a slice:

```
text = 'caramelosticosis'
print(text[::-1])
```

(By the way, best not to use `string` as a variable name as it is also the name of a [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html))

Comment: Yes - i actually used chaine, but for reference purposes i wrote string, Thanks!